# .obj exportation is not working properly

Tags: mesh, modifiers, export, unity, obj

[image]

So i this problem with the exportation, the obj file looks fine in the 3d viewer but when I import it in unity it's all wrong, I applied all the modifiers but with no results.I tried to export it as fbx but it's the same.

[image]

This is how it should look, I don't know if there is some problem with the mesh but I don't know how to check that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nvm I found the answer, it is pretty easy actually. You need to go to the "show overlays" tab (the 3'rd one)

[image]

Then press the drop-down and enable "Face Orientation"

[image]

After that, all of the faces should blue on the outside and red on the inside.
To inverse them u need to select the wrong ones and go to "Mesh" then "Normals" and "Flip".
(Or Alt+N and Flip)

[image]

Also, u can apply a solidify modifier so that u completely hide the red part.

Easy